# Android TimePicker not working

Tags: android, android-timepicker

Simple timepicker function is failing with Fatal Exception - NullPointerException and java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException on following line :

```
int hour = time_picker.getCurrentHour();
```

Fragment_main.xml :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.calapp1.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

<TimePicker
    android:id="@+id/timePicker1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dp" />

<TextClock
    android:id="@+id/textClock1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="TextClock" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
    android:text="Show Time"
    android:onClick="setTime"
     />
```

MainActivity.java :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

TimePicker time_picker;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    time_picker = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker1);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }

}

public void setTime(View v)
{

    int hour = time_picker.getCurrentHour();
    int minute = time_picker.getCurrentMinute();

    try{
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "select time is "+hour, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "problem", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}



@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

}

Can you please assist?

Thank you,
Yogesh.

Comment: Describe your problem exactly. where does the code fail? what did you try? what kind of error do you get. pls edit your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You timepicker is in the fragment layout and not in the activity layout. Activity `onCreate()` is too early to find it in the activity view hierarchy.

Move the `findViewById()` to fragment `onCreateView()` and change it to `rootView.findViewById()`.

Answer (score 0):

Please be noted that you have your timepicker in Fragment_main.xml and you're trying it in the onCreate where the contentview is set as  `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` so please move the line to `onCreateView()` and use `rootView.findViewById()`. That will srely solve the issue.